# Update observable from the custom components in knockout 3.2

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-components

I am trying to use custom components from **knockout 3.2** and update the observable from within the component. Here is an example of my custom component:

```
ko.components.register('voting', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        var self        = this;
        this.votes      = params.votes;
        this.yourVote   = params.yourVote;

        this.callback   = function(num){
            self.yourVote(parseInt(num));  // here I am updating
            self.votes( self.votes() + parseInt(num) );
        };
    },
    template: { element: 'voting-tpl' }
});
```

The template for it looks like this:

```
<voting params="votes: votes(), yourVote: yourVote()"></voting>
<template id="voting-tpl">
    <div data-bind="click:function(){callback(1)}">Up</div>
    <div data-bind="text: votes"></div>
    <div data-bind="click:function(){callback(-1)}">Down</div>
</template>
```

The problem is that when I [click on Up/Down function in my full JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5by1gys/). I get

> Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you
>   specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't
>   pass any parameters.

Surely I can use `var a = new Vm();` and update it from inside of the component with `a.yourVote(num);` but this breaks the whole idea of components.

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should pass your observables as parameters to custom component, instead of creating dependencies:

```
<voting params="votes: votes, yourVote: yourVote"></voting>
```

You can read more here [knockout 3.2 components](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html) (How params are passed to the component)

> The params are provided to initialize the component, like in the
>   component binding, but with a couple of differences:
>
> - If a parameter creates dependencies itself (accesses the value of an
>     observable or computed), then the component will receive a computed
>     that returns the value. This helps to ensure that the entire component
>     does not need to be rebuilt on parameter changes. The component itself
>     can control how it accesses and handles any dependencies.

[**Fixed JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8f16uLuL/)